# JavaFX Graphs screenshot

Tags: java, javafx

Recently I've encountered a problem when working with JavaFX. What i'm trying to do is to have my graphs displayed in the scene and export it to a PNG file after clicking a button. The problem is that when i export them to file they're disappearing from the scene (exported image is ok though). Here are the parts of code i'm using:

```
@FXML
private PieChart pieChart;
(...)

ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList(new PieChart.Data("a",
                    13), new PieChart.Data("b", 10),
                    new PieChart.Data("c", 5),
                    new PieChart.Data("d", 22),
                    new PieChart.Data("e", 30),
                    new PieChart.Data("f", 5),
                    new PieChart.Data("g", 15));
    pieChart.setData(pieChartData);
    pieChart.setAnimated(false);

@FXML
private void handleNewButtonClick(ActionEvent event)
{
    Charts.savePieChartToFile(pieChart.getData(), "diagram_file.png");
}

(...)

public static void savePieChartToFile(
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData, String path)
{
    PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
    Scene sceneForChart = new Scene(pieChart, 800, 600);
    WritableImage image = pieChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
    File file = new File(path);
    try
    {
        ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's how it looks like:
[image: Disappearing graph]

I'd be thankful for some advice on this matter.

Comment: Can you just snapshot the piechart directly, instead of creating a new one. I.e. `Image image = pieChart.snapshot(null, null);`. The chart API is pretty badly written: I think the issue is that the data has a reference to the node that represents it (ok, appallingly badly written), so if you reuse the data, the node is moved to the new scene.

Comment: Using the piechart directly crashes the app, that's why i'm creating new one.